# Laravel 5.4 API route

Tags: php, post, laravel-5, routes

My web routes are working, however I cannot POST to my api routes, I receive `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. I think this is a csrf token problem as GET works, but I can't figure out how to fix it. I am using Postman to simulate api requests.

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'devices',
    ],
],
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('api', ['uses' => 'DeviceController@api']);
```

kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

This is an upgrade from an older version of Laravel that was working, I upgraded by installing a fresh copy of Laravel 5.4 then copied over my code, changing it as needed.

Comment: From where and how you are calling ? if from ajax share that code ?

Comment: @detective404 I am using Postman to do the call. I am calling www.mydomain.com/api with a POST request

Comment: Hey @meeeee Did you find solution for this problem. I have similar problem If it solved at your side then let me know.

Comment: @DenisBhojvani Yes i did. I was trying to use http when I am forcing https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I made this same mistake a month ago. The problem is that I wasn't using https. Its weird how I get MethodNotAllowedException for that, I guess that threw me off.

Comment: Brilliant X'D loving the honesty :p

Answer (score 1):

Send `_token` value like this with POST request

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/your url",
        data: {_token:$("input[name='_token']").val(),'other':'Other value'}
    }).done(function( response ) {
        ....
    });
```

Comment: This does not make sense to me when using an api. the token should not be needed

Comment: which url you are calling ?

Comment: you need to comment `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` in kernel.php to not verify because you are not able to send `_token` value from postman

Comment: I cant do that as I need the token to work with the web portion of the site. I did try adding the api route to the csrf token except method but that didn't help. It might not be a token problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help